# AsciiDoc: "Unresolved directive in ... include:: ..." when rendering .adoc file in Firefox with Asciidoctor.js Live Preview

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

Using the Firefox Add-on "Asciidoctor.js Live Preview" I get the output

```
Unresolved directive in Summary.adoc - include::a.adoc[]

Unresolved directive in Summary.adoc - include::b.adoc[]
```

when rendering an AsciiDoc source file containing

```
include::a.adoc[]

include::b.adoc[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that Firefox prevented the extension from including the files. To circumvent this behaviour:

1. open the Firefox configuration with the URL **about:config**
2. find the parameter **security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy**
3. set the value of this parameter to **false**

With this setting I succeeded in rendering the file.